# Dynamic filtering on Django admin form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a three simple models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)    

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Session(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
```

It is hard to uers to select Task from all tasks in database. I want to allow user to reduce number of choices by filterting task by tag. So, user can select tag and then find task (in reduced amount of tasks). It is possible to implement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) in your admin class:

```
@admin.register(Task)
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('tag',)
```

Comment: list_filter should be tuple by documentation not an array

Comment: @iklinac list_filter can be used in this way.I tried it at my end.

Comment: Comment wasn't intended to discard solution as "working" but for it to improve by following documentation